# Выражение "Заставь дурака богу молиться"

Tags: фразеология

В выражении "Заставь дурака богу молиться" - Бог с прописной или строчной буквы?

Answer (score 1):

Когда речь идет о Едином Боге в общечеловеческом и общерелигиозном смысле этого слова, то, вне всякого сомнения, нужно писать с большой буквы.
Если же речь о языческих богах, о боге в знечении идола ("люди делают из золота бога"), тогда с маленькой.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что здесь возможно написание с заглавной.
Бог здесь выступает в прямом значении, высшего разума (хотя и используется в бытовом выражении), да и речь идёт именно о прямом процессе обращения к Богу, процессе моления.
В таких случаях высокий религиозный стиль требует заглавной, а "гражданские" правила пока допускают строчную. Но я бы всё-таки оставил заглавную.

Answer (score 0):

А я бы всё же написала со строчной буквы, потому что в данном фразеологизме слово "Бог"  уже, как мне кажется, не обозначает высшее существо, потому что словосочетание "богу молиться" значит - "что-то делать". Здесь, я думаю, не следует рассматривать фразеологизм как "прямой процесс обращения к Богу", потому что фразеологизм - это всегда иносказание.

Comment: Да нет... Совсем не "что-то делать". Подразумевается прямой процесс молитвы. При этом отвешивают поклоны - поясные или стоя на коленях. И "дурак", естественно, не рассчитает амплитуду - и разобьёт лоб о крест или икону.

"По обычаю верующие во время молитвы становились на колени и низко кланялись, почти касаясь лбом пола. В пословице с осуждением говорится о недалёком, неумном человеке, который чрезмерным усердием и старанием вредит себе."
© http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki